# How can i repeat previous request in ofetch

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, fetch, refresh, refresh-token

I have next api client. I use ofetch

https://github.com/unjs/ofetch

```
import { $fetch, FetchContext, FetchOptions, Headers } from 'ohmyfetch'
import AuthModule from '~~/repository/modules/auth'


export interface ApiInstance {
  auth: AuthModule
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const refreshTokenCookie = useCookie('refreshToken')

  const fetchOptions: FetchOptions = {
    baseURL: nuxtApp.$config.public.apiBase,

    onRequest(ctx: FetchContext): Promise<void> | void {
      const tokenCookie = useCookie('accessToken')

      ctx.options.headers = new Headers(
        {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenCookie.value}`
        }
      )
    },

    async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        await $fetch('/auth/refresh', {
          baseURL: nuxtApp.$config.public.apiBase,
          method: 'POST',
          body: { refresh_token: refreshTokenCookie.value }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  const apiFetcher = $fetch.create(fetchOptions)

  const modules: ApiInstance = {
    auth: new AuthModule(apiFetcher),
  }

  return {
    provide: {
      api: modules
    }
  }
})
```

In the onResponseError function I make a refresh request if the error is 401.
After the refresh I need repeat the previous request.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Thanks:)

**Update**
I did refresh

```
import { $fetch, FetchContext, FetchOptions, Headers } from 'ohmyfetch'
import { useAuthStore } from "~/store/auth"
import AuthModule from '~~/repository/modules/auth'
import CategoryModule from '~/repository/modules/category'

export interface ApiInstance {
  auth: AuthModule
  category: CategoryModule
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const refreshTokenCookie = useCookie('refreshToken')
  const accessTokenCookie = useCookie('accessToken')
  const route = useRoute()
  const authStore = useAuthStore()

  const fetchOptions: FetchOptions = {
    baseURL: nuxtApp.$config.public.apiBase,

    onRequest(ctx: FetchContext): Promise<void> | void {
      ctx.options.headers = new Headers({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessTokenCookie.value}`
      })
    },

    async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        try {
          const newTokens = await modules.auth.refresh({
            refreshToken: refreshTokenCookie.value
          })

          accessTokenCookie.value = newTokens.access_token
          refreshTokenCookie.value = newTokens.refresh_token
          authStore.setAccessToken(newTokens.access_token)
          authStore.setRefreshToken(newTokens.refresh_token)


          options.headers = new Headers({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${newTokens.access_token}`
          })

          return apiFetcher(request, options)
        } catch (error) {
          if (route.path !== 'auth') {
            navigateTo('/auth')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const apiFetcher = $fetch.create(fetchOptions)

  const modules: ApiInstance = {
    auth: new AuthModule(apiFetcher),
    category: new CategoryModule(apiFetcher),
  }

  return {
    provide: {
      api: modules
    }
  }
})
```

But now i cannot get data from request on my page

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import type { ApiInstance } from "~/plugins/api"

const { $api }: { $api: ApiInstance } = useNuxtApp()

const categories = ref([])
useAsyncData(async () => {
  categories.value = await $api.category.getAll()
})
</script>
```

My category module

```
import HttpFactory from '../factory'
import type { Category } from "~/types"

class CategoryModule extends HttpFactory {
  private resource = '/backend-category'

  async getAll(): Promise<Category[]> {
    console.log(1)
    return await this.call(this.resource)
  }
}

export default CategoryModule
```

So function getAll() is called once before refresh